# Spark DataFrame not allowing multiple dynamic column list with window function in group by

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

```
sample code:- 
val list=Seq("symbol").map(column=>col(column))
    val windowedCount = stockDs
      .withWatermark("time", "500 milliseconds")
      .groupBy( list:_*,
        window($"time", "10 seconds")
      )
      .sum("value")
```

> `Error : _*' annotation allowed here
>   (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters) .

Comment: also, I have tried below code but not succeed yet:   .groupBy(Seq(col("b")) ++ Seq(col("b"), col("b")):_*,
        window($"time", "10 seconds")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`groupBy` signature is](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@groupBy(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset)

> ```
>  def groupBy(cols: Column*): RelationalGroupedDataset
> ```

So you can provide only a single sequence argument:

```
stockDs
  ...
  .groupBy(list :+ window($"time", "10 seconds"): _*)
```